# Opacity 0 Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is my first SO post, please let me know how to do better!

I have a function that clears the  by setting the opacity to 0, it works, but it will make my file massive if if try to set up a whole spread sheet with each  having the same function bar different ids,

Ideally, the way I want this to play out, is that  clears itself, and  will clear all  blocks. And I want to do it without having to write duplicate functions.

Is it possible to have a function set over classes? I have tried with no success
Or is there a better way to run the JavaScript, like somehow `onclick==clear.self` ?

```js
function Xf1() {
  f1();
  f2();
}

function f1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("a1");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function f2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("a2");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
```

```html
<tr>
  <th onclick="Xf1()">Clear all</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td onclick="f1()" id="a1"> text1</td>
  <td onclick="f2()" id="a2"> text2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't add event listeners to all the child elements. Rather add it in the parent element and make use of the custom data attribute and make use of the event bubbling and capturing concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

1. start by adding a class to the table element
2. add a class to the "clear all" heading
3. add a click event listener to the table element

If the click event target is a `td` element, set its opacity to 0.

If the click target is the clear all heading, set all `td` elements to opacity 0. You can do that by querying the table for `td` tags and then using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/forEach) to change the opacity for each of them.

```js
const myTable = document.body.querySelector(".my-table");

myTable.addEventListener("click", event => {
  const target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName == "TD") {
    target.style.opacity = 0;
  }
  if (target.classList.contains("clear-all")) {
    myTable.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(item => (item.style.opacity = 0));
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="my-table">
  <thead>
    <th class="clear-all">Clear all</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="a1">text1</td>
      <td id="a2">text2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

set an id to parent tag then set onclick to that elements children.

if you set "container" as id you will have something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementById("container");

for (let i = 0; i < elements.children.length; i++) {
  elements.children[i].onclick = function () {
    elements.children[i].style.opacity = "0";
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding onclick to each `td` element. Have it in `table` element. Like this

```js
    
    document.querySelector("#table").addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
      if(event.target.dataset.type==='clear'){
        const ids = ['a1', 'a2'];
        ids.forEach((ele)=>{
         document.querySelector(`#${ele}`).style.opacity = '0';
        });
        return;
      }
      event.target.style.opacity = "0";
    }
    )
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th data-type="clear">Clear all</th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="tableRows">
    <td id="a1"> text1</td>
    <td id="a2"> text2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This has solved My problem, Thankyou!!

Comment: @BloodWorks if this answer solved your problem, it's best you mark it by clicking on the checkmark to the left

Comment: thankyou!! @Corrl